# How do I pass a quoted string with -D to gcc in cmd.exe?

Tags: gcc, cmd, gnu, quotes

With `gcc` (and possibly other compilers as well) it's possible to define a macro outside the source file like so:

```
c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_INT=45 foo.c -o foo.exe
```

This will define `DEFINED_INT` to 45 which can be seen when compiling

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("The define was: %d\n", DEFINED_INT);

  return 0;
}
```

The compiled `foo.exe` will then print *45* when executed.

Now, what I have no clue of is how do I pass a *quoted string* instead of an int. So, the printf would then be something like

```
  printf("The define was: %s\n", DEFINED_STRING);
```

and the compilation like so:

```
c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_STRING="foo bar baz" foo.c -o foo.exe
```

but this doesn't work, the respective line will be

```
printf("The define was: %s\n", foo bar baz);
```

(that is: without the desired quotes).

```
c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_STRING=\"foo bar baz\" foo.c -o foo.exe
```

doesn't work, neither, as gcc now tries to find the files *bar* and *baz* (the error message is:

```
gcc.exe: bar: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: baz": Invalid argument
<command-line>:0:16: warning: missing terminating " character
```

So, how can I get the compiler along with cmd.exe to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
-DDEFINED_STRING="\"foo bar baz\""
```