# How does gnu-make deal with quotes in the makefile if called in cmd.exe?

Tags: makefile, gnu, quotes, cmd

I have a c source file to which I want to pass a quoted macro via gcc's `-D` 
command line flag. (See also [How do I pass a quoted string with -D to gcc in cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928595/how-do-i-pass-a-quoted-string-with-d-to-gcc-in-cmd-exe)). And I am working in cmd.exe.

It's possible to compile the program directly like so:

```
c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_STRING="\"foo bar baz\"" foo.c -o foo.exe
```

But if I create a *makefile* with the following content

```
foo.exe: foo.c
    c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_STRING="\"foo bar baz\"" foo.c -o foo.exe
```

and then execute a `make`, gnu's make will try to invoke `/bin/sh` and the backslashes of the path to gcc.exe dissapear:

```
gcc-4.7.0/gcc/config/avr -c c:/temp/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/gcc.c -o o/gcc/gcc.o
/bin/sh: c:MinGWbing++.exe: command not found
make: *** [o/gcc/gcc.o] Error 127
```

Stragnly enough, this doesn't happen when I use `-DDEFINED_STRING=foo` (that is: without quotes).

`make -v` prints `GNU Make 3.81`

Answer (score 0):

Making in a Windows environment has many nuances. In this case, it looks like you just need to escape your backslashes like so:

```
foo.exe: foo.c
    c:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe -DDEFINED_STRING="\"foo bar baz\"" foo.c -o foo.exe
```

Alternatively, switch them to forward slashes or the preferred /cygdrive/c style. As a side note, I seem to recall that Windows style filenames are no longer supported in dependencies as of Make 3.81.

You might also want to set the SHELL variable and review some of the caveats [mentioned](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) in the manual and in the NEWS file included in the source tarball.