# NDK and libiconv

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, libiconv, android.mk

I'm trying to build libiconv through the ndk.  I'd never used make files before so I'm learning as I go and used this suggestion as a starting point:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/AS1nkxnk6m4/EQm09hD1tigJ

This is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CLFAGS := \
    -Wno-multichar \
    -D_ANDROID \
    -DLIBDIR="c" \
    -DBUILDING_LIBICONV \
    -DIN_LIBRARY \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    lib/iconv.c \
    lib/relocatable.c \
    libcharset/lib/localcharset.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libcharset/include/ \

LOCAL_MODULE    := libiconv 

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The issue I'm having is that none of the defines exist when it compiles.  **LIBDIR** is the first problem as it reaches *localcharset.c*:

```
#ifndef LIBDIR
# include "configmake.h"
#endif
```

.

```
localcharset.c: In function 'get_charset_aliases':
localcharset.c:136:15: error: 'LIBDIR' undeclared (first use in this function)
localcharset.c:136:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once
```

and can't find *configmake.h*.  I bypassed this issue and ran into more define related issues.    Basically none of the flags were defined.  Anyone know what I did wrong or why it might not define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes needed to be escaped.  I couldn't find this in the documentations.

-DLIBDIR=\"c\"

Comment: This is because double quotes are recognized by the shell and removed. Alternatively you can wrap it with single quotes `-DLIBDIR='"c"'` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14030713/1688185 for more details).